# Tuple Error When Using Queryset to Match a user with a specific foreign key to key

Tags: python, django, tuples

I'm trying to create an api that returns Orders that satisfy these requirements: Status = ready, no other driver has picked it up, and the driver is assigned to that venue. The driver should only be able to view orders from their assigned location. Everytime I call api, I get the error saying: 'tuple' object is not callable.

How do I format and return all the items in the query, properly in a JsonResponse? I do not understand the error.

Here is the result of the query

```
TypeError at /api/driver/orders/ready/
'tuple' object is not callable

 /apis.py in driver_get_ready_orders
@csrf_exempt
def driver_get_ready_orders(request):
    driver = CustomJWTAuthenticator().authenticate(request)[0].driver
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(
        status=Order.READY, driver=None).order_by("-id"),
    if driver.dispensary:
        queryset = queryset(dispensary=driver.dispensary ...
                            )
    orders = Order.objects.filter(
        queryset,
        many=True,
        context={"request": request}
▶ Local vars
Variable    Value
driver  
<Driver: Malcom Brooks>
queryset    
(<QuerySet [<Order: 10>, <Order: 8>]>,)
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/driver/orders/ready/?
```

Here is my Api:

```
   def driver_get_ready_orders(request):


    driver = CustomJWTAuthenticator().authenticate(request)[0].driver
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(
        status=Order.READY, driver=None).order_by("-id"),
    if driver.dispensary:
        queryset = queryset(dispensary=driver.dispensary
                                        ).all()
    orders = Order.objects.filter(
            queryset,
            many=True


    )

    return JsonResponse({"orders": orders.data})
```

Order and Driver model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    PICKING = 1
    READY = 2
    ONTHEWAY = 3
    DELIVERED = 4

    CANCELED = 5

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PICKING, "Your Order Is Being Picked Right Off The Plant!"),
        (READY, "Picked, Weighed, And Ready For Delivery."),
        (ONTHEWAY, "The Best Bud Is Heading Straight To Your Door."),
        (DELIVERED, "Delivered"),

        (CANCELED, "Canceled/Refunded")
    )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    dispensary = models.ForeignKey(Dispensary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(
        Driver, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

def __str__(self):

    return str(self.id)

class Driver(models.Model):
    Active_License = (
        ('License_Status', (
            ('active', 'Active'),
            ('suspended', 'Suspended')
        )),
    )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)


    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='driver_photos/', blank=False, default='')

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='driver')
    dispensary = models.ForeignKey(
        Dispensary, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems here:

1. you used a trailing comma, and thus wrapped the result in a singleton tuple;
2. a `queryset` is *not* callable, hence `queryset = queryset(dispensary=driver.dispensary)` is not valid;
3. neither can you filter with `.filter(queryset)`. You likely here want to use a *serializer*:

You thus hould rewrite this to:

```
# no trailing comma
queryset = Order.objects.filter(status=Order.READY, driver=None).order_by('-id')
if driver.dispensary:
    queryset = queryset.filter(dispensary=driver.dispensary)
orders = OrderSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```